# Procedure or function 'biinsertcustomer' expects parameter '@custid', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

`@custid` is used for return value. but gives error

> Procedure or function 'biinsertcustomer' expects parameter '@custid', which was not supplied.

I tried this code without using `@custid` and `scope_identity` and it works.

Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.biinsertcustomer

@cust_name varchar(50),
@contactname varchar(50),
@address nvarchar(max), 
@status varchar(50),
@custid int output  
AS
if(@status='insert')
Begin   
if not exists ( select cust_name from tblcustomer where cust_name=@cust_name)
insert into tblcustomer(cust_name,contactperson,address) values(@cust_name,@contactname,@address)
set @custid=scope_identity()
RETURN @custid
End
```

Execution:

```
con.open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("biinsertcustomer", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_name", txtcustname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactname",txtcontactname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "insert");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
custid =Convert.ToInt32( cmd.Parameters[@custid].Value.ToString());
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the output parameter *before* calling the procedure. Then you can get the parameter value out afterwards:

```
SqlParameter customerParameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
customerParameter.ParameterName = "@custid";
customerParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
customerParameter.Size = 100;

cmd.Parameters.Add(customerParameter);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string custid = customerParameter.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: String[9]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: 'System.Data.IDataParameter' does not contain a definition for 'size'

Comment: Sorry, should be `SqlParameter`. instead of `IDataParameter`.